# Running dotnet core api from compiled dll

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to run a dotnet core WebApi on a MacOs. Running the project with `dotnet run` works fine, since it runs from source code.

Now i want to pack the Api and run it on other machine, so for that i use the following command

`dotnet publish WebApiX.sln -f netcoreapp2.0 -c Release -o ../output -r osx.10.12-x64`

which packs the whole application and their dependencies. After this i want to start the web server with `dotnet WebApiX.Api.dll` but i'm getting the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: pathFormat    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.FileLoggerExtensions.AddFile(ILoggerFactory
>   loggerFactory, String pathFormat, LogLevel minimumLevel,
>   `` IDictionary`2 `` levelOverrides, Boolean isJson, `` Nullable`1 ``
>   fileSizeLimitBytes, `` Nullable`1 `` retainedFileCountLimit)

This exception is generated in Configure method presented on Startup class

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // Configure Midleware
    loggerFactory.AddFile(Configuration.GetSection("LogsLocation").Value);

    app.UseMiddleware<SerilogMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorWrappingMiddleware>();

    app.UseAuthentication(); 
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

For testings purposes i tried to remove the line LoggerFactory.. 
and its strange because the error now is different.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddMvc' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder app, Action`1 configureRoutes)
   at WeidertAuth.Api.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) in /Users/mariomarques/Documents/Avnoconn/Projects/WEIDERT/WeidertServices/weidert.auth/WeidertAuth.Api/Startup.cs:line 249
```

Comment: Try publishing with Debug configuration and see if error persists.

Comment: it may help if you share that part of the code where you use `.AddFile` method

Comment: Running with debug configuration results in the same thing.
I guess its something related to Configurations. Question is edited to include the Configure method presented on Startup class (which is the method that originates the exception)

Comment: Can you share the related section in your `appSettings` file? `Configuration.GetSection` will be looking for a section called "LogsLocation", if that doesn't have a value then that could be where the issue lies

Comment: I've ensured it has a value. In fact i removed that line and now the error is different

Comment: It's going to sound like a really stupid question, but based on the new error that you've provided do you have the line `services.AddMvc()` in your ConfigureServices method?

Answer (score 0):

you should add a runtime identifier to project file (.csproj), like the following:

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Once done, you should restore the project and publish it using cmd:

```
dotnet restore

// publish for macos
dotnet publish -r osx.10.12-x64 --output bin/dist/osx
```

Then you can find an executable of the project within project at the following path:

**MyProject/bin/dist/osx**

Hope you'll find this useful.